# Why is the iphone view size is set to 480

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

When I use interface builder i see that the size of the view is 480X300 why is that? isnt the iphone screen 960X640px?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are actually "points". Depending on `UIDevice` `scale` parameter points convert to either 480*320 (for normal display) OR to 960*640 (for retina display).

Comment: I have an image that is 1500X640px and I want it to fit in the view vertically and be able to scroll to the sides. i keep getting the image centered so I can scroll up and down to although its the size of the screen and not more.

Comment: If you want it to be displayed at these dimensions on normal screen - you have to add "retina version" of it twice the size (3000x1280). And name it with `@2x` suffix. So if your pic is foo.png, then name retina version as foo@2x.png.

Comment: the problem is that i am getting the imge through wifi as a byte array so I cant do that. any other suggestions?

Comment: Eimantas: Why would it need to be 3000 x 1280? It's already larger than the screen.

Comment: @Peter - it wasn't clear if image was an asset or something external.

Answer (score 3):

You can also read the Apple docs which explains the difference between points and pixels in detail: [Points Versus Pixels](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW7)

Answer (score 1):

And also note that the "missing 20 pixels" (300 instead of 320) are due to the status bar.  If you select "status bar unspecified" in "simulated user interface elements" in the CMD-1 attributes inspector then you get the full 320 height.

Answer (score 0):

Older iPhone (like iPhone 3GS) has 480x320 display, and iPhone 4 has 960x640 display (called retina display).
On the retina display, any user interface elements will be scaled up to 2X.
By the way, these are not "points", but just "pixels". If they were "points", iPhone 4 would be bigger than iPad.

Answer (score 0):

To understand how to handle screen/display size depending on iPhone versions, read this article : [Supporting High-Resolution screens](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15)